# Optimize MySQL UPDATE Query

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to run this query, and the table that's being updated has about 10,000 rows. The query takes so long to execute that I can't even be bothered to wait for the return.

In a couple hours this table will have 100,000 rows and so, it's going to take 10 times longer than it does already. Anyone have any ideas to optimize it?

```
UPDATE

`wpsapi4`.`product_details` AS `pd`,
`r2r`.`partmaster` AS `pm`,
`r2r`.`partpriceinv` AS `ppi`,
`r2r`.`manufacturer` AS `m`

SET

`pd`.`product_name`=`pm`.`ItemName`,
`pd`.`data_source`='R2R',
`pd`.`partmaster`=`pm`.`id`,
`pd`.`pu`=``.`ppi`.`DistributorPartNumberShort`,
`pd`.`description_raw`=`pm`.`ItemDescription`,
`pd`.`dealer_price`=`ppi`.`MSRP`,
`pd`.`weight`=`pm`.`Weight`,
`pd`.`vendor_name`=`m`.`ManufacturerName`

WHERE

(
`pm`.`ManufacturerNumberShort`=`pd`.`vendor_number`
OR
`pm`.`ManufacturerNumberLong`=`pd`.`vendor_number`
)
AND
`pm`.`id`=`ppi`.`DistributorPartNumberShort`
AND
`ppi`.`DistributorID`=2
AND
`pm`.`ManufacturerID`=`m`.`id`
```

If you think it could be to do with the table structures then please say so, I can't really change the structure at this point but if you know where the indexes should be then that would be great. Indexes are already optimized on the r2r database.

Comment: My that's a lot of backticks.

Comment: You can optimize update statements the same way you optimize select statement. Run explain on the same query with the same table joins and where clause to see what's happening.

Comment: @JamWaffles: Yeah love my back ticks :), people tell me not to use them but I ignore them. I remember when I first started in mysql and I kept having errors because I was using reserved words, so now I backtick everywhere. + it helps if I want to do a find/replace

Comment: True. Personally, I think they're quite messy, but it's all a matter of personal preference. I haven't yet come across a need to use reserved words as field names, but I may do in the future!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The columns to index are the ones reference in your where clause.

Consider adding the following:

1. An index on the pm.ManufacturerNumberShort column.
2. An index on the pm.ManufacturerNumberLong column.
3. An index on the pm.id column.
4. An index on the pm.ManufacturerID column.
5. An index on the ppi.DistributorPartNumberShort column.
6. An index on the ppi.DistributorID column.

**Based on input from Darhazer:**

Consider adding one or more of the following:

1. An index on the pm.ManufacturerNumberShort, pm.id, and pm.ManufacturerID columns.
2. An index on the pm.ManufacturerNumberLong, pm.id, and pm.ManufacturerID columns.
3. An index on the ppi.DistributorPartNumberShort and ppi.DistributorID columns.

Comment: Single indexes are not as fast as compound ones (index_merge should be used or one of indexes should be choosen to resolve the where clause), and in case of update, every index adds to the time needed for write.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing an `OR` on Vendor Number, I would start by making sure that you have an index on vendor number on both tables.

Looks to me that the other columns already should have indexes.

Comment: @lcarus: Yeah thanks, actually the tables from the database named r2r are fully optimized already, indexes everywhere. I'm working on this product_details table at the moment and I can see some non standard field types that might be slowing it down. It's got things like varchar(500) etc, I didn't even think that was possible, lol